# Left Join And vs Where on Second Table

Tags: sql

Is there any difference in the output between these two queries?

Both tables only have one column - `id`.

Table A: {1,2,3,4,5};
Table B: {5,6,7,8,9}

```sql
Select *
from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id
where tableB.id = 5;
```

```sql
Select *
from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id and tableB.id = 5;
```

Comment: Yes there is a difference,
Putting the filter inside the left join clause will return all of the rows, because it is a left join and it allows the "right side" of the join to be null, which means that it will return all of the rows that exist in tableA, regardless whether the tableB.id is 5 or not,
Whereas the "where" filtering will return only rows who have tableB.id = 5
Please see the fiddle example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ec345/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the difference is that on the first one, if the left join doesn't find a match for A in B, it will leave the row, and then remove it using the `WHERE` clause. In other words, it will be equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`, because `B.id` is always null if there is no match.

For the second query, by contrast, if the query doesn't find a match for `A` in `B` using *both* conditions, it will leave the `A` row and put nulls in `B.id` for all non-matching rows.

```sql
WITH a(id) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)),
     b(id) AS (VALUES (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id = 5;

WITH a(id) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)),
     b(id) AS (VALUES (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND b.id = 5;
```